# Streaming audio to a "speaker server" in linux

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, linux-device-driver

Is there a way to stream all audio from a laptop (which has low quality speakers) to a desktop with much better speakers in linux (on both computers)? I think that this would have to be a kernel driver, since it would have to fit under the alsa system to make it application transparent.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pulseaudio has network support, and it is the only way I know of to do low-level sound device streaming.

Comment: Thanks. I guess half the battle is knowing what to google! I found a good tutorial on how to do this: http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/582-stream-music-wirelessely-using-pulseaudio-server-device-chooser